# The ring hom $\mathbf{Z}\rightarrow A$

Tags: ring-theory, notation

Let $A$ be a ring with idenity. Is there a standard notation for the canonical ring hom $\mathbf{Z}\rightarrow A$?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: The fact that there hasn't been a single answer for 10 minutes means there probably isn't one. Even if there is, it isn't well-known.

Comment: I mean, I see no problem with saying "consider the map $\mathbb{Z}\to A$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\underline{~~~~\eta~~~~} $$
In a [monoidal category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category), a [monoid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid) (or algebra) is a triple $(A,e,m)$, where $A$ is an object, $e : 1 \to A$ (unit) is a morphism and $m : A \otimes A \to A$ (multiplication) is a morphism such that $m \circ (m \otimes A) = m \circ (A \otimes m)$ (associativity) and $m \circ (e \otimes A) = \mathrm{id} = m \circ (A \otimes e)$ (unit axiom). For example, a **ring** is a monoid in the monoidal category of abelian groups, equipped with the usual tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and with $1=\mathbb{Z}$. In this concise description of rings, the (multiplicative) unit element of the ring actually corresponds the unit morphism $e : \mathbb{Z} \to A$. Therefore, I would denote this morphism by $e$ (eins) or $1$ (one) or $u$ (unit). You can also stress the dependency of $A$ and write $e_A,1_A$ or $u_A$. You can also view monoids as special monads, and in this setting the unit is often denoted by $\eta$. This is done for example in Mac Lane's book and at the nlab. It is also quite standard in texts about [bialgebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bialgebra) (in particular Hopf algebras), which are usually written as $(A,\eta,\mu,\varepsilon,\Delta)$, where $\eta$ is the unit, $\mu$ is the multiplication, $\varepsilon$ is the counit and $\Delta$ is the comultiplication.

So probably $\eta$ should be an "almost standard" notation.